# HealthCloud HL7 REST API Specification

Tags: rest-api, json, health-cloud

I'm working to implement HealthCloud with an external system. HealthCloud provides the `services/apexrest/HealthCloudGA/HL7` REST endpoint to accept HL7 messages and parse them into the Electronic Health Record objects included in the HealthCloud package.

One of the main issues is lack of documentation, let alone examples. I've gone through many different formats specified by HL7 (JSON, XML, plain text) and have learned the JSON format expected by SF is undocumented and not particularly standard. My current test message JSON is as follows:

```
{ 
    "MSH": {
        "MSH_1": "|^~\\&",
        "MSH_2": "",
        "MSH_3": "APPLICATION",
        "MSH_4": "FACILITY",
        "MSH_5": "HEALTHCLOUDGA",
        "MSH_6": "SALESFORCE",
        "MSH_7": "199912271408",
        "MSH_8": "",
        "MSH_9": "ADT^A01",
        "MSH_10": "20060126130405",
        "MSH_11": "D",
        "MSH_12": "2.5",
        "MSH_16": "AL"
    },
    "PID": {
        "PID_3": "454721",
        "PID_5": "DOE^JOHN^^^^",
        "PID_12": "USA"
    },
    "NK1": {
        "NK1_2": "ROE^MARIE^^^^",
        "NK1_3": "SPO",
        "NK1_4": "(216)123-4567",
        "NK1_6": "EC"
    },
    "PV1": {
        "PV1_2": "O",
        "PV1_3": "168 ~219~C~PMA^^^^^^^^^",
        "PV1_8": "277^ALLEN MYLASTNAME^BONNIE^^^^",
        "PV1_22": "2688684",
        "PV1_48": "199912271408",
        "PV1_54": "002376853"
    }
}
```

When I POST this to the endpoint I receive the following error:

```
{
    "Messages": [
        {
            "summary": "Parse Failure",
            "severity": "ERROR",
            "scope": "Context.triggerEvent",
            "detail": "triggerEvent not Found.",
            "code": "HL7-002"
        },
        {
            "summary": "Parse Failure",
            "severity": "ERROR",
            "scope": "Context",
            "detail": "Unable to determine Context",
            "code": "HL7-008"
        }
    ],
    "isDebug": true,
    "Data": null,
    "Context": {
        "versionId": "2.5",
        "triggerEvent": null,
        "sendingFacility": "FACILITY",
        "sendingApplication": "APPLICATION",
        "receivingFacility": "SALESFORCE",
        "receivingApplication": "HEALTHCLOUDGA",
        "mshObject": null,
        "messageCode": "ADT^A01"
    }
}
```

From my understanding of the HL7 format and this error message, the system isn't able to parse the `MSH_9` key for the message type `ADT` and the trigger event `A01`. The documentation I've found simply states that the endpoint exists (HealthCloud Implementation Guide) or is a link to the generic Industries API documentation which does not specify the expected request format for the HealthCloud HL7 API.

What is wrong with my JSON that is causing SF to fail to parse the sample message?

Comment: With this being a brand new API, you may need to reach out to support and file a Case if the documentation doesn't provide the information you need. The number of users here who'll be able to help you will be extremely limited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who arrives here wondering what's wrong, the Health Cloud Industries API is currently in an unusable state. After filing a case Salesforce has determined there is a bug with the API on their end and is currently working to provide a fix.

Comment: What is the status of the ability of Health Cloud to create and parse HL7 messages? We are looking for Apex classes to help to create and parse HL7 messages. Please point us to the documentation.